# How to add index and value to a object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

How to add index and value to a object, below is my code, I tried to add index and value in loop, but it shows error `undefined is not an object ($data.file_list_image.i.sequence)`, why and how to solve it ?

tried to get json data and send to server side

desire data

```
$data = {file_list_image: {0: {sequence: 1, intro: }, 1: {sequence: 1, intro: }, }}
```

js

```
var $el = $content_list.find('.content-list-gallery-file-list');
var file_length = $el.length;
var file_image_length = 0;
var file_embed_youtube_length = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
    if ($el.eq(i).attr('data-type') == 0) { // console.log('img');
        file_image_length++;
    } else if ($el.eq(i).attr('data-type') == 1) { // console.log('video');
        file_embed_youtube_length++;
    }
}

var $data = {};


for (var i = 0; i < file_image_length; i++) {
    var $file_list = $el.filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-type') == 0 && $(this).attr('data-tmp-id') == i;
    });

    var sequence = $file_list.attr('data-sequence');
    var intro = $file_list.find('.intro textarea').val();


    $data.file_list_image.i.sequence = sequence;
    $data.file_list_image.i.intro = intro;
}

console.log($data);
```

HTML

```
<div class="content_list">
  <div class="content-list-gallery-file-list" data-type="0" data-tmp-id="1" data-sequence="0">
    <div class="intro"><textarea></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-list-gallery-file-list" data-type="0" data-tmp-id="0" data-sequence="1">
    <div class="intro"><textarea></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-list-gallery-file-list" data-type="1" data-tmp-id="2" data-sequence="2">
    <div class="intro"><textarea></textarea></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `file_list_image` an array of objects? Share the structure of the data you are working with. Some example would give better clarity. If however it is an array of objects then try doing  `$data.file_list_image[i].sequence`. Also, I don't understand why you are naming the variable `data` as `$data`. It's a lil misleading.

Comment: Please post your code completely

Comment: thanks for reply, thats' all my code,  I tried to make data kind like  {file_list_image: {0: {sequence: 1, intro: letter}, 1: {sequence: 0 , }}

Comment: Your doing some very weird stuff here. Where do you get $el from? also the example of the desired data structure here seems weird to me it looks like you want an array of objects

Comment: A JSFiddle would help a lot.

Comment: @vibskov It seems that you use an object in json format. Is it correct?

Comment: I saw your updated code. Still where does $content_list get initialized?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I update html, maybe much clear??

Comment: @reporter I tried to make json data and send to server side

Comment: I suspect this is all about something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7x4gme/).

Comment: Yes, @Regent thanks so much!   would you leave an answer below, then I can accept this

Comment: posting as comment so Regent can post answer; Alternative with some more dynamics being read from the associated HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/3qvxunxp/

Comment: @vibskov you're welcome. Yes, since this example is correct one, I should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of how it can be done by initializing object properties at correct time:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7x4gme/)

```
var $data = {};
$data.file_list_image = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    $data.file_list_image[i] = {};
    $data.file_list_image[i]["sequence"] = "seq" + i;
    $data.file_list_image[i]["intro"] = "in" + i;
}
console.log($data);
```

By the way, `$data.file_list_image[i]["sequence"]` (same with `intro`) can also be `$data.file_list_image[i].sequence`

[Fiddle example with original HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7x4gme/1/).